# Is there any limitation for python pprint printing large data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-data, large-files, pprint

Sorry if my English is bad, I speak Korean as mother tongue.

What I was trying is to pprint a large list, of which size is like `len(repr(lst)) == 64xxx`, to a text file.

but when I tried something like

```
from pprint import pprint as p

f = open(fname, mode='a+')
p(a_lst, f)
```

it only printed about 80% of list, and the rest 20% were cut.
and I also tried halving list and call pprint twice, but that also didn't work.

so I had to do this instead

```
print(a_list, file=f)
```

which worked. but why pprint didn't print all the list? is there some size limitation?
or maybe was my RAM or etc not enough?

edit: I tried with pprint once more, and it worked and couldn't reproduce the same result (the cut result). Maybe it was temporary bug I think, but I can't come up with the cause of the bug.

Comment: Are you looking at the file after your program closed it?

Comment: I would probably use `json.dump()` or `f.write()` on a large list if I could. For what it is worth though, this works locally for me `pprint.pprint(list(range(1_000_000)), f)`

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproducible example that builds an array like the one that fails you? Is it a list of objects? Dictionaries? Strings?

Comment: @Daviid it is 2d list, `len(lst)` is 95, `len(lst[0])` is 24, and elements like `lst[0][0]` is str with length of 24 such as `'000000000111000000000000'`

Comment: No errors on my end, are you sure it's just 95 sublists of 24  24-characters strings?

Comment: more likely an issue with buffers on the output terminal program than with pprint.

Comment: @jsbueno does 'output terminal program' mean some system side low level printing function behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
import random

# Define the dimensions of the 2D list
first_level = 95
second_level = 24
lst = []

for _ in range(first_level):
    second_level_list = []
    for _ in range(second_level):
        # Generate a random binary string of length num_cols
        random_string = ''.join(random.choice('01') for _ in range(24))
        
        # Append the random string as a list to lst
        second_level_list.append([random_string])
    lst.append(second_level_list)

from pprint import pprint as p

f = open("output.txt", mode='a+')
p(lst, f)
```

and didn't get any errors.

The full array was in the output file even without doing `f.close()`